# Activity with variable content

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I need to create an `activity` with an `ActionBar`, so that if you press the action bar buttons, the contents of the `activity` display the same information in different `layout` (one is a pie chart and the other a `listview`).

I don't want to use tabs or a `viewpager`, so what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build each view in a separate fragment, and use the actionbar buttons to set the current visible fragment.